# Do I need to investigate HTTP 401 cached by Fiddler during the HttpWebRequest post to ASP.NET WebApi server

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, http-status-code-401

I am totally new to WebApi and WebRequests and other things.
After hours of googling, finally, I managed to do POST using C# and HttpWebRequest.
When I do HttpWebRequest in debug mode using Visual Studio I do not get any exceptions.
My app work as I accept , I get data to webApi server and also get back data.
To be sure how my app communicate with WebApi server I start Fiddler Web Debugger.
During the POST to WebApi, Fiddler chace 401 errors

```
 {"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

Steping step by step in debuger I fund that following lines of code doing 401 error

> ```
>         HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
>         wr.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
>         wr.Method = "POST";
>         wr.ContentType = "application/json";
>         byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
>         wr.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
>         using (System.IO.Stream dataStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
>         {
>             dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); //After this line of code Fidler Chace HTTP 401
>         }
> ```

Later in code when I do wr.GetResponse() I do get status 200OK.

My questions are :
Do I need to redesign my code to avoid this error in Fiddler ?
Is there other methods to fill HttpWebRequest whit jsonSting beside using GetRequestStream() ?

Answer (score 1):

If your service is enabled with Windows Authentcation, then in Fiddler, you can select the option to automatically authenticate using your logged on credentials by going here:

Composer tab -> Options tab -> Automatically Authenticate

Also, why not use HttpClient from System.Net.Http?...It has a much better and easy programming model...example:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9095/");

HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Customer>("api/values", cust).Result;
```

Comment: Thanx on answer I switched to using HttpClient But fiddler still cache HTTP 401 but now it happens in:  var dnnUser = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<DnnLoginUser>().Result;

Comment: I am unable to understand your statement "still cache HTTP 401"...are you seeing this error even after setting the Fiddler settings as above?...Could you share your repro project?